# Is it possible to make the tab completion on command-line mode case insensitive?

Tags: command-line, neovim

When I try to type in my directory to open my file, for example `~/Desktop`, the tab completion doesn't work at the point of `~/d`, since the completion only works on the capital letter.

I already wrote the following on `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`, though it doesn't seem to be effective on the command-line case:

```
set ignorecase
```

Can I make the tab completion on the capital letter on the command-line even though I type in a lowercase letter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the [`'wildignorecase'` option](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27wildignorecase%27)

> When set case is ignored when completing file names and directories.
>   Has no effect when 'fileignorecase' is set.
>   Does not apply when the shell is used to expand wildcards, which
>   happens when there are special characters.